# Android sqlite update not updating as expected, double-quoted string literal or no such column Errors occur

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, sql-update, android-sqlite

I pass the correct data through to the db modifier function, set the values in the ContentValues, but can not seem to get it to update. I am trying to update by name (a PK) which is of type string, I have done this before with and ID of type int without issues.

here is some code:

```
companion object {
        private val version = 1
        private val name = "mydatabase.db"
        val TABLE_NAME = "countires"
        val COLUMN_NAME1 = "name"
        val COLUMN_NAME2 = "gold"
        val COLUMN_NAME3 = "silver"
        val COLUMN_NAME4= "bronze"
        val COLUMN_NAME5= "total"

    }
    fun updateCountry(country:Country){
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val values = ContentValues()
        var trx = country.name
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME1, country.name)
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME2, country.gold)
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME3, country.silver)
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME4, country.bronze)
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME5, country.total)
        db.update(TABLE_NAME,values, "$COLUMN_NAME1=\"$trx\"", null)
        db.close()
    }
```

In the run second, I get the following message:
W/SQLiteLog: (28) double-quoted string literal: "Austria"
If I change the query statement to:

```
        db.update(TABLE_NAME,values, "$COLUMN_NAME1=$trx", null)
```

I get the following error:
(1) no such column: Austria in "UPDATE countires SET bronze=?,silver=?,gold=?,name=?,total=? WHERE name=Austria"
D/AndroidRuntime
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Austria (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: UPDATE countires SET bronze=?,silver=?,gold=?,name=?,total=? WHERE name=Austria
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)...

To be clear there is a column with that name in the DB. A simple search in the db inspector of:

```
select  *  from countires
where name = "Austria"
```

Returns the desired row.

There is clearly something wrong with my update command and I am not sure why it does not work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `?` placeholder for the parameter that you want to pass and use the 4th argument of the method `update()` for its value inside an array:

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "$COLUMN_NAME1 = ?", arrayOf(trx))
```

Comment: Good idea, I tried that and got the same error: W/SQLiteLog: (28) double-quoted string literal: "Austria"
error again.

Comment: @James_B log the value of `trx`. It is a string like `Austria`, right? No double quotes.

Comment: Yeah it comes from an array of strings. Looking into the debug, I see the data is correct and the past data was updating properly when using the ? placeholder. It seems the database Inspector was not updating for some reason. Opening the DB file shows it to be working. Restarting the IDE now shows it updated.  
Sorry about that, seems I had it working before I asked this question but the ide was acting up!